# EF Core 7 - Adding and removing empty migration changes the snapshot

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql

First, I add a migration (I haven't changed anything, and it should be empty):

```
Add-Migration Test
```

I get the following migration:

```cs
public partial class Test : Migration
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Also because of a NuGet update the snapshot changes as follow:

```cs
modelBuilder
    .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "7.0.15") // This line changes from 13 to 15
    .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 63);
```

Next, I remove the migration:

```
Remove-Migration
```

The two files of empty migration will be removed, and the snapshot version goes back to 13, but weirdly EF removes three properties from two different tables in the snapshot file.

[image]

I'm using EF Core 7 with Npgsql provider.